# How to display all rows in AgGrid paginationPageSizeSelector?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

code

```
             gridOptions = {
                 pagination: true,
                 paginationPageSize: 10,
                 paginationPageSizeSelector: [10,20,30]
                 etc....
                }
```

Firstly in AgGrid Options

`paginationPageSizeSelector = [10,20,50]`   will be there
Question how to add all to it like this `[10, 20, 50, All]` and define `pageSize` of `ALL` as total rows
or
Secondly how to display a custom `pagenationPageSizeSelector` like this
`paginationPageSizeSelector = ['10', '20', '1000 (slow)', 'All')]`

Note: Please provide answers related to AG Grid only

Answer (score 1):

I have created custom pagination in ag-grid in angular like

```
   <ng-select [clearable]="false" [items]="numberList" bindLabel="value" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"
            class="customPagination pagination-icon" (change)="onPageSizeChanged($event)" [searchable]="false">
        </ng-select>
```

**TS**

```
 numberList = [
    { id: 1, value: '10' },
    { id: 2, value: '25' },
    { id: 3, value: '50' },
    { id: 4, value: '100' },
    // { id: 5, value: 'All' }
  ];
     onPageSizeChanged(newValue: any): void {
        this.pageSize = newValue.value;
        this.selectedOption = newValue;
        newValue.value == 'All' ? this.params.onPageSizeChanged(this.totalCount) : this.params.onPageSizeChanged(newValue.value);
      }
```

now

```
async onPageSizeChanged(newValue: any) {
    this.pageSize = Number(newValue);
    this.isClientSide = this.gridData?.length == Number(newValue) ? false : true;
    delayedFunctionCall(this.changePageSizeForAll, 0, this, newValue);
  }
```

that function add in aggrid.component.ts file

Comment: This I can do bro. Thanks for the answer. I want to do inside agGrid only

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/server-side-model-pagination/

please check this url

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
one way is we can have a state variable and manipulate it accordingly with table rows when tabledata loads. but this is not efficient method.

```
gridOptions = {
       pagination: true,
       paginationPageSize: 10,
       paginationPageSizeSelector: this.pageSizes,
     }
```